# ValueError: Duplicate plugins for name projector

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard

Running `tensorboard --logdir log_dir` I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/.local/bin/tensorboard", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(run_main())
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorboard/main.py", line 64, in run_main
    app.run(tensorboard.main, flags_parser=tensorboard.configure)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/absl/app.py", line 300, in run
    _run_main(main, args)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/absl/app.py", line 251, in _run_main
    sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorboard/program.py", line 228, in main
    server = self._make_server()
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorboard/program.py", line 309, in _make_server
    self.assets_zip_provider)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorboard/backend/application.py", line 161, in standard_tensorboard_wsgi
    reload_task)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorboard/backend/application.py", line 194, in TensorBoardWSGIApp
    return TensorBoardWSGI(plugins, path_prefix)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorboard/backend/application.py", line 245, in __init__
    raise ValueError('Duplicate plugins for name %s' % plugin.plugin_name)
ValueError: Duplicate plugins for name projector
```

What can be a reason of this problem?

Comment: Did you have a look at this? Does it match your requirement? https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/22676

Comment: I get this using tensorflow 2.0.0.-tc0, no pytorch. Also there is no second tensorboard installation.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. I only have 1.14.0 installed, no pytorch. I did briefly install tensorflow 2.0.0-rc1 while debugging to see if that had the same problems (it all worked fine) but then removed it. Does pip3 uninstall 2.0.0-rc1 packages not remove all the configurations or something?
```
$ pip3 list | grep tensor
tensorboard          1.14.0              
tensorflow           1.14.0              
tensorflow-estimator 1.14.0
```

Comment: to me it's weird, I uninstalled the nightly as suggested. Then installed tensorflow and tensorboard (the latter with both pip and conda) but nothing worked. How did you install tensorflow and tensorboard? (btw I am using pytorch for tensorflow)

Answer (score 49):

If you have two versions of tensorboard installed in your system,you need to uninstall one of them.

I was stuck this for hours but I finally fixed it using:

Worked like a charm:
https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/22676

```
pip uninstall tb-nightly tensorboardX tensorboard
pip install tensorboard
```

Comment: to me it's weird, I uninstalled the nightly as suggested. Then installed tensorflow and tensorboard (the latter with both pip and conda) but nothing worked. How did you install tensorflow and tensorboard? (btw I am using pytorch for tensorflow)

Comment: For me it's `pip uninstall tb-nightly; pip install -U tensorboard --force` works.

Answer (score 17):

I ran into the same issue after installing tensorflow==2.0.0-rc2. Uninstalling tensorboard did not help.

The culprit in my case was tb-nightly package:

```
#python3.7 -m pip list | grep tb
tb-nightly           1.15.0a20190806
```

After removing the package and reinstalling TensorFlow, tensorboard started to work properly.

Comment: how did you uninstall the nightly package?

Comment: to me it's weird, I uninstalled the nightly as suggested. Then installed tensorflow and tensorboard (the latter with both pip and conda) but nothing worked. How did you install tensorflow and tensorboard? (btw I am using pytorch for tensorflow)

Answer (score 14):

I got same error, when I had two versions of tensorboard. In my Tensorflow 2.0 environmnet, except core Tensorflow lib, I could see  other libs where installed from TF 1.14 version.

Do a `pip list` and see what versions of tensorflow libs are there. In my system I had

```
...
tensorboard                   1.14.0              
tensorflow-estimator          1.14.0              
tensorflow-gpu                2.0.0rc0            
tensorflow-serving-api        1.14.0              
termcolor                     1.1.0               
tf-estimator-nightly          1.14.0.dev2019080601
...
```

Here is what I did:

```
pip uninstall tensorboard
pip install --force-reinstall tf-nightly-2.0-preview
```

Answer (score 5):

Run the following code if it shows two `tensorboard` installed on your system remove one.

```
import pkg_resources

for entry_point in pkg_resources.iter_entry_points('tensorboard_plugins'):
    print(entry_point.dist)
```

Comment: Woah! Best solution right here.

Answer (score 3):

For Ubuntu users, go to: `/home/$USERNAME/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/` or whatever path is displayed in the error.
There you will see 2 folders with names something like this **tensorboard** and **tensorboad-2.5.0.dist-info**. Remove the second one.

Answer (score 1):

One easy workaround for these sorts of issues is to call tensorboard via `python -m tensorboard.main`. For example, replace `tensorboard --logdir ./model --port 6006` with `python -m tensorboard.main --logdir ./model --port 6006`. Much easier!

Answer (score 1):

It took me a day to figure it out finally.
In my case there were **two folders** for tensorboard at

** C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\ **

Keep the tensorboard folder for your preferred version and **delete** the other.

Answer (score 0):

For me what worked was to uninstall the nightly build which is usually installed with pip since tf is usually installed with pip:

```
pip uninstall tb-nightly
```

then I installed tensorboard with conda

```
conda install -y -c conda-forge tensorboard
```

note I am using pytorch with tensorboard: https://pytorch.org/tutorials/recipes/recipes/tensorboard_with_pytorch.html

I did not need to install tensorflow but I did it in a second test since it was complaining about not having full features:

```
pip install tensorflow
```

since for some reason conda doesn't instlal tensorflow well (I tried it with conda-forge -c channel and it took to long to do anything).

---

Note you might need to uninstall more stuff as the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/59408145/1601580:

```
pip uninstall tb-nightly tensorboardX tensorboard
```

suggested

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem. I found the problem creator was `tb-nightly`.
I had installed it to resolve **"Cannot start tensorboard in Jupyter Notebook"**
problem but after one day it arises ***"duplicate plugins for name projector"*** error.

I have tried `pip uninstall tb-nightly` but unfortunately it didn't work for me. The jupyter notebook was stacked in running.

Finally,I went to my site-packages folder`C:\Users\User\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages` and delete the tb-nightly folder,as well as from RecycleBin and it worked.[image]

Answer (score 0):

In short: You are very likely to have **both** `tb-nightly` and `tensorboard` installed. Nightly dependencies can easily mess thing sup.

Uninstall BOTH:

```
pip uninstall tb-nightly tensorboard
```

And install one that is compatible with your TF version (either `tensorboard` or `tb-nightly`):

```
pip install tensorboard          # or tb-nightly
```

Answer (score 0):

As explained in [this answer from Github](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/22676#issuecomment-537630837), it can also be caused by a ghost copy of tensorboard, `-ensorboard`.

To check if it is the case you can do a `pip list` and look for the following warning message on the first line:

> WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ensorboard

If it is the case you need to manually delete the folders in your python environment using the location given by the warning (something like `appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages` for Windows). There should be two folders to delete: `~ensorboard` and `~ensorboard-2.14.1.dist-info`