# TF 2.0 TensorBoard 2.0.2 ValueError: Duplicate plugins for name projector

Tags: tensorflow, plugins, tensorboard, pkg-resources

I had some problem with my tensorboard, when I start to launch it, it raises the error:

```
ValueError: Duplicate plugins for name projector
```

I followed [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58743709/12066144) and it appears there are 2 tensorboards installed on my system:

```py
import pkg_resources

for entry_point in pkg_resources.iter_entry_points('tensorboard_plugins'):
    print(entry_point.dist)
```

The output is:

```
-ensorboard 2.0.1
tensorboard 2.0.2
```

As the comment says, I should remove one (so I guess `-ensorboard 2.0.1`). But how can I do that ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the folder containing the packages. There should be two folders, one for each version. Delete one of those folders and you will be golden.